# Non exceptional case, array out of bounds

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, split

I understand that what I'm trying to do is a bit of a hack, but it's interesting nonetheless.

I'm in a situation where it is quite possible that an array might not have as many items as I expect.

Here's the concept:

```
namespace TESTAPP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string derp = "foooooo";
            //The split is important, you might not have the character there to split by
            Writer(derp.Split('x')[0] ?? ".");
            Writer(derp.Split('x')[1] ?? ".");
        }

        private static void Writer(string writeme)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(writeme ?? "..");
        }
    }
}
```

Naturally, I'm not too surprised when executing the above prints:

```
foooooo

Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at TESTAPP.Program.Main(String[] args) in [snip]\TESTAPP\Program.cs:line 15
```

How should I deal with this situation logically? A `try/catch` block seems overkill.

Comment: How do you *want* to handle it? Do you need to throw an exception, or can you recover from this? What does it mean to your program if there aren't enough strings?

Comment: `derp.Split('x')[1] ?? "."` suggests that if there's nothing in `derp.Split('x')[1]` that the character `"."` would be printed instead.

Comment: You should get a reward for a most unreadable code ;) The problem is in `derp.Split('x')[1]`. You can't check if [1] is null, because it dosen't extist.

Comment: @KamilT Thanks :p Yes that is a major source of the problem

Comment: I'll make an answer out of it, pleasu upvote it if you find it helpfull ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll want to split only once, and not for every part again:

```
string derp = "foooooo";
string[] parts = derp.Split('x');
// parts == { "foooooo" }
// parts.Length == 1
```

Now you have an array that contains a number of parts, so you can simply check the `Length` property before accessing each part:

```
Writer(parts.Length > 0 ? parts[0] : ".");
Writer(parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : ".");
Writer(parts.Length > 2 ? parts[2] : ".");
Writer(parts.Length > 3 ? parts[3] : ".");
Writer(parts.Length > 4 ? parts[4] : ".");
```

*or*

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Writer(parts.Length > i ? parts[i] : ".");
}
```

*Output:*

```
foooooo..
...
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example.. iterate over the results:

```
foreach (var item in derp.Split('x'))
    Writer(item);
```

If there is another specific case.. then this obviously may not fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the conditions appropriately and don't try writing it all inline:

```
var split = derp.Split('x');
Writer(split.Length >= 2 ? split[1] : ".");
```

If there are going to be lots of such conditionals and each one defaults to a different value if none exists in the input, you can resize the array beforehand:

```
var split = derp.Split('x');
Array.Resize(ref split, 2);

Writer(split[1] ?? "."); // this is now safe
```

Note that the above looks bad as written because `[1]` does not say anything about the contents of that array element, so it's arguably not obvious why the default should be `"."`.

Answer (score 1):

Define a `GetOrDefault` extension method, like this:

```
// If you need this method to work with collections or even IEnumerables,
// you can change implementation to get the count differently.
// This should be sufficient for arrays, though:
static T GetOrDefault(this T[] items, int index) {
    return items.Length > index ? items[index] : default(T);
}
```

Now you can use this method as follows:

```
Writer(derp.Split('x').GetOrDefault(0) ?? ".");
Writer(derp.Split('x').GetOrDefault(1) ?? ".");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `derp.Split('x')[1]`.

You can't check if the [1] element is null, because it DOESN'T EXIST. Imagine a situation:
I give you one bucket and put 'fooooo' into it.
Then I ask You, `"Is the second bucket empty?"`.
You can't say `"yes"`, you can't say `"no"`. The bucket just doesn't exist, so you'll say `"ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"` - there is no second bucket, so I can't check if it's empty ;)

Comment: You can define a maximum length of array to return with `String.Split()`, can you also define a minimum?

Comment: I don't think so, you can only try some workarounds, like creating an array of the size you need and copy values from array created in string.Split().

Answer (score 0):

if this is *not* exceptional situation, do not use exception, if you can.

in this concrete case, you *can* avoid using exceptions and use just simple bounds control, like (just an example):

```
var splitted = derp.Split('x');
if(splitted.Length > 1) {
   Writer(derp.Split('x')[0] ?? ".");
   Writer(derp.Split('x')[1] ?? ".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `if` statement:

```
var result = derp.Split('x');
if (result.Length > 0)
    Writer(result[0]);
else
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array returned by `Split`

```
var splitOutput = derp.Split('x');

foreach (var s in splitOutput)
     Writer(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conquer.

If you expect the value to exist:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string derp = "foooooo";
    var parts = derp.Split('x');
    if (parts.Length != 2)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Expected string to have to dot X delimited values. Actual string: " + derp);

    Writer(derp.Split('x')[0] ?? ".");
    Writer(derp.Split('x')[1] ?? ".");
}
```

If you expect the values to be missing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string derp = "foooooo";
    var parts = derp.Split('x');

    if (parts.Length > 0)
        Writer(parts[0]);
    else
        Writer(".");

    if (parts.Length > 1)
        Writer(parts[1]);
    else
        Writer(".");

}
```